# Can anyone explain NBA lottery to me?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am trying to understand the odds of the **NBA lottery**, here is how it works

> There are 14 teams participating in it, of those 14 teams only one team will get the No 1 pick, to lottery is used to determine that team.

Here is how the process goes

> There are 14 ping pong balls each one having number between 1 to 14(representing the team),
>   First they calculate all possible 4 teams(balls) combinations out of 14 teams(balls) {here 1-2-3-4 is same as 4-2-3-1- or 4-3-2-1}

This comes as 1001, of these 1001 they delete {11,12,13,14} combination so that results into 1000 possible combinations. Up this point I understand.

After that they divide the 1000 combination into 14 teams, with the first team getting **250 combinations**,second team **199**, **156** third team, **119 fourth team** etc. and say that odds of the first team is 0.25%, second team 0.199%, third team 0.156%. {Here order of first,second.third team is pre decided}

> My question is that How the odds of first team are 0.25%, According to my calculation For each X team there are **286** combination containing X (13C3), so How is it that this number is being completely ignored?  I don't understand the 250/1000 expression, And it is possible that more than 1 team gets a ball representing their team, since every team has got 286 balls in 1000 balls sample space. What is the tie break then.

Comment: I dont see how the 286 is related to the 250. Can you be specific how do they divide the 1000 combinations into 14 teams? it is obvious if the first team get 250, then ${250\over 1000}=25\%$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The four balls from fourteen effectively form a random code, which the NBA officials look up on a prepared list to determine which team gets first draft pick.

The 250, 199, 156 etc. are arbitrary numbers designed to add to 1000, and determine how many codes are pre-assigned to each team (250 for the previous season's worst performing team, 199 for the second worst etc.)

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NBA_Draft_Lottery) has more